# How to get specific value in html of a Dictionary in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I have a dictionary `<key, value>` and want to access the value of a specific `key` in `html` . which is the possible way?

```
export interface ICollection<T> {
    add(key: number, value: T);
    containsKey(key: number): boolean;
    item(key: number): T;
    keys(): number[];
    values(): T[];
}

export class Collection<T> implements ICollection<T> {
    private items: { [index: number]: T } = {};

    public containsKey(key: number): boolean {
        return this.items.hasOwnProperty(key);
    }

    public add(key: number, value: T) {
        this.items[key] = value;
    }

    public item(key: number): T {
        return this.items[key];
    }

    public keys(): number[] {
        var keySet: any[] = [];

        for (let item in this.items) {
            if (this.items.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                keySet.push(item);
            }
        }

        return keySet;
    }

    public values(): T[] {
        var values: T[] = [];

        for (var prop in this.items) {
            if (this.items.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                values.push(this.items[prop]);
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
}

export const FIELDS = new Collection<String>();

FIELDS.add(100002, "First Name");
FIELDS.add(10003, "Last Name", );
FIELDS.add(100032, "Contact ID", );
```

Now what I want in my html template is, to access the value `FirstName` Something like this:

```
 <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
       <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">First Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="firstName" class="form-control" [ngModel]="FIELDS['100002']" readonly/>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to get access??

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope that your HTML reads from is the Component's scope.  So all you need to do is assign FIELDS as a member of your Component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FIELDS } from './wherever-you-export-fields-from';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'your.html'
})
export class DemoComponent {
    const FIELDS = FIELDS;
}
```

You can then use `[ngModel]="FIELDS['100002']"`.